How to convert \pmatrix to \begin{pmatrix}
I would like to convert \pmatrix to \begin{pmatrix}.
I found a solution for \case here where it is said that this can be done by
\let\amscases\cases
\makeatletter
\def\cases{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\plaincases\amscases}
\def\plaincases#1{\begin{cases*}#1\end{cases*}}
\makeatother

But I haven't the least idea how to modify this for \pmatrix?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\pmatrix{a & b \cr
         c & d}
\end{equation}

\end{document} 

Gives the error massage:
Package amsmath Error: Old form `\pmatrix' should be \begin{pmatrix}. \pmatrix

I'm seeking for a solution like
\let\amspmatrix\pmatrix
\makeatletter
\def\pmatrix{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\plainmatrix\amspmatrix}
\def\plainmatrix#1{\begin{pmatrix*}#1\end{pmatrix*}}
\makeatother

since I have a document with hundreds of the old plain TEX pmatrices which would be a horror to replace them by \begin{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix}.

please clarify your question, providing a test document. \begin{\pmatrix} would be a syntax error and produce no useful output given any standard definitions. what do you want it to do? did you mean \begin{pmatrix} ?

@David Carlisle: I meant \begin{pmatrix}. I would like that I can use \pmatrix but as for \cases it should be handles with the amsmath environment \begin{pmatrix}.

you need to edit the question, not only to fix that typo but to provide a complete small document that shows the problem. the latex format has a command \pmatrix{....} and the amsmath package has an environment \begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix} so you shouldn't have to convert anything, just use the command form if you have not loaded amsmath and (better) use the environment form if you have loaded amsmath

thanks for editing although you still ask for \begin{\pmatrix} in the title and text of the question

by far the simplest fix for your document is to remove \usepackage{amsmath} is that an acceptable answer?

This was also my first suggestion, but unfortunately not. We have to use amsmath.

I'm not sure that makes sense (even though I posted an answer) whatever authority is imposing a requirement that you use amsmath presumably(?) requires that the document conforms to that syntax loading it but then redefining its commands to have a different syntax may make latex happy but whether it actually meets the stated requirement seems doubtful.

Given
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\pmatrix{a & b \cr
         c & d}
\end{equation}

\end{document} 

The most direct fix, as the document is using teh format's version of \pmatrix not amsmath is to remove amsmath
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\pmatrix{a & b \cr
         c & d}
\end{equation}

\end{document} 

runs without error.
If however you do want amsmath for other reasons, you can use the suggested code, except the environment you want is pmatrix not the non existing pmatrix*
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\amspmatrix\pmatrix
\makeatletter
\def\pmatrix{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\plainmatrix\amspmatrix}
\def\plainmatrix#1{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\pmatrix{a & b \cr
         c & d}
\end{equation}

\end{document} 


That amazing! Thank you so much. Exactly what I need. By the way, what is the difference between pmatrix and pmatrix*?

@PhillipBachler the difference is that amsmath defines pmatrix and does not define pmatrix* so your suggestion gives an undefined command error.

Thanks again! To clarify my somehow strange question. I have to deal with many very old Tex documents which will partly used in a publication, and converting everything by hand would have lasted for ages. So your answer saved me and my colleagues weeks, I suppose.
